# easiest way to undo one file change in svn

Tags: svn

Let's say I have the following situation:

```
myrepo/
  foo.txt
  bar.txt
  baz.txt
  quux.txt
  bingo.txt
```

In rev 419, I changed foo.txt, bar.txt, and bingo.txt.

Now I discover an error and I would like to keep foo.txt from rev 418, but leave the changes in bar.txt and bingo.txt from rev 419 intact, so I can commit rev 420 so its foo.txt is the same as rev 418.

How can I do this with a minimum of hassle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how, I have rolled back the changes of a previous commit.

The reverse merge : svn --revision (version to revert):(version below it) <. or filename>

```
svn merge --revision 419:418 foo.txt
svn commit -m "Reverting commit ver:419 for foo.txt"
```

Comment: You can shortcut with `svn merge --change -419 foo.txt`. A negative change, will revert that revision, makes it easier to remember in my opinion.

Comment: `-c -REV` (or `--change -REV`) simplifies the syntax a bit by only requiring the revision to revert

Comment: cool, thanks, I figured it was a merge but I can never keep those things straight. :/

Comment: @Jason S: I kind of have made that as my practice and do not use the negative change. That is also an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortiseSVN, you can right click on the file in question and click "Show Log". In the commit log, find the revision for the file you want to revert, right click the file and click "Revert changes from this revision". Then commit the change to your branch.

[image]